# another question on surds and how to use math symbols in this site

Tags: exponentiation

$$\sqrt{ 3x }= x + \sqrt {3}$$

this is what i tried

$$\sqrt{ x }= (x + \sqrt {3})^2\\
= x^2 + 3
$$

Give x in the form 
$$A \sqrt {B} + C $$
Can you show me how this is done step by step.

The answer I have in the book is:

$$\frac {1}{2} \sqrt{3} + \frac {3}{2} $$

Comment: Is it  $\sqrt{3x} = x + \sqrt 3$?

Comment: The latex codes for $\sqrt{x}$ and $\pi$ are `\sqrt{x}` and `\pi`.

Comment: yes how do you use those symbols

Comment: Just type `$\sqrt{x}$` for the mathematical expression. Any math should be between two dollar signs

Comment: @Ragnar And why is $\pi$ relevant here?

Comment: @amWhy, The user asked for root and pie, and I assumed he meant $\pi$.

Comment: @Ragnar I see now: I didn't see the last sentence in the post. Your comment makes perfect sense now! ;-)

Comment: Sorry I want to know how to use different symbols so I can show my questions clearly

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all $(\sqrt {3x})^2 = 3x$.

And furthermore,  $$(x + \sqrt 3)^2\neq x^2 + 3$$ 
Recall, when squaring a binomial:
$$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$$

Starting from the beginning: we need for $3x \geq 0 \iff x \geq 0$ for the left hand side of the following equation to be defined in the reals:

$$\sqrt{3x} = x + \sqrt 3$$

Squaring both sides gives us $$\begin{align} 3x = (x +\sqrt 3)^2 & \iff 3x = x^2 + 2\sqrt 3 x + 3\\ \\ &\iff x^2 + (2\sqrt 3 - 3)x + 3 = 0\end{align}$$

You can use the quadratic equation to check for solutions, throwing out any solution for which $x \lt 0$. Recall, for any quadratic equation of the form $$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$ we can find its roots $$x_i = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ In your equation, $$a = 1,\\\;b = 2\sqrt 3 - 3,\;\\ b^2 = (2\sqrt 3)^2 - 2(3\cdot 2\sqrt 3) + (-3)^2 = 12 - 12\sqrt 3 + 9 = 21 - 12\sqrt 3,\\ c = 3$$

Comment: Thanks, @DonAntonio. I wouldn't have caught that without the aid of your "eyes"!

Comment: My "dreaming" eyes, @amWhy ...:) ? +1

Comment: my maths is really weak can you explain it in simple terms please

Comment: I've given you the equation to solve; I've given you the quadratic equation. I've even given you explicitly what values to use for $a, b, c$. There's no simpler way to put it other than "plug the values a, b, c into the quadratic equation to find its roots, and omit any roots $x \lt 0$. $x_i$ stands for a root of the quadratic equation. $$x_i = \dfrac{-(2\sqrt 3 - 3) \pm \sqrt{(21 - 12\sqrt 3) - 4\cdot 1\cdot 3}}{2\cdot 1} $$ Work on simplifying this.

Comment: After squaring both sides should it be $$ x^2 + 2x \sqrt{3} + 3 $$

Comment: Yes, I just put the $2\cdot\sqrt 3$ before the $x$ term

Comment: @Sami (Sorry, I didn't catch your message until now!) Just feeling slightly "burned out" at MSE. It will likely pass ;-)